# Save Credentials for wireless network Greyed out

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking

When I try to managing a wireless network to save my credentials, that option is greyed out. I thought I might need administrator permissions but I don't see any option to do so. I know from other people it should be possible.

Edit: my wireless network adapter is Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205

[image]

[image]

Comment: Done, but i don't think these settings are network card specific.